# <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", :media => "all" %> <----- This piece of code is not allowing my ROR application to load locally

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

After installing Twitter bootstrap, I ran 'Rails server' and now the application will not load.

This is the error

```
cannot load such file -- less
  (in C:/Sites/cardMS/app/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap_and_overrides.css.less)
```

And highlighted in the screen is this line

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", :media => "all" %>
```

Does anyone have any suggestions as to where I may have gone wrong?

Comment: If you installed Bootstrap via [bootstrap-sass](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass), make sure you followed the directions *exactly* -- it doesn't use the standard Rails manifest files.

Comment: I installed the twitter-bootstrap-rails gem. Im on Windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To temporarily get around the problem and remove the error your could create an empty file at

```
C:/Sites/cardMS/app/assets/stylesheets/
```

called

```
/bootstrap_and_overrides.css.less
```

However you should look further for the root cause which might be that you have not correctly followed the process that copies the bootstrap files as indicated by colinm

Answer (score 0):

Use a bash like shell like cygwin (as I'm noticing that you seem to be on windows):

Install grunt-cli globally with

```
npm install -g grunt-cli.
```

Navigate to the root `/bootstrap/` directory, then run `npm install`. npm will look at the `package.json` file and automatically install the necessary local dependencies listed there.